# Unable to resolve url. Received error- Reverse for 'satchmo_search' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, satchmo, webfaction

I'm installing Satchmo following these instructions: http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?pid=10579#p10579

When I want to check my installation, I get the following error:

```
$ python manage.py satchmo_check
Checking your satchmo configuration.
Using Django version 1.2.5
Using Satchmo version 0.9.2-pre hg-unknown
The following errors were found:
Unable to resolve url. Received error- Reverse for 'satchmo_search' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from satchmo_store.urls import urlpatterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^myproject/', include('myproject.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Using the `reverse` function on the command line, I get:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Dec  1 2010, 06:29:57) 
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse(satchmo_search)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'satchmo_search' is not defined
```

I'm new to Satchmo and Django, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the urls you are importing.

Change your urls.py file like so:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from satchmo_store.urls import urlpatterns

urlpatterns += patterns('',

    # Your urls go here

)
```

or

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from satchmo_store.urls import urlpatterns as satchmo_urls

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # Your urls go here

)

urlpatterns += satchmo_urls
```